# How to make one function instead of 3 or more for a visualization in d3 to then add highlight when hovering over nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have visualized 3 trees with d3 but I have repeated my code, and now I want to add `highlighting the same nodes in different trees when hovering over a node in a tree` but this I cannot do as I see with this structure of code that I have now.

The d3 code I have now for the three different trees (so I have put the code three times in three different functions draw(), draw1() and draw2()):

```
<script>

//here i get the data
var data = {{data.chart_data | safe }}    

draw("#svg1", "#url");
draw1("#svg2", "#url");
draw2("#svg3", "#url");
draw3("#svg4", "#url");

function draw(selector, url){

    console.log(data);

    // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = data[0]

update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.cues; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  }
};


// Second tree
function draw1(selector, url){


    console.log(data);

    // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = data[1]

update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.cues; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  }
};


// third tree
function draw2(selector, url){

    console.log(data);

    // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = data[2]

update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.cues; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  }
};


// fourth tree
function draw3(selector, url){


    console.log(data);

    // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = data[3]

update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.cues; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  }
};
</script>
```

(notice that the only change is the `root = data[]` for every tree, so that I can access different elements of the list). Can this be done differently so that I have only one function draw() and I change the `root = data[0]` dynamically in d3? And then as I said previously I want to add highlighting, so that when I click on one node the node with the same name in the second and third tree will be highlighted as well. I got [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8326869) example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh8up130/11/) and modified to look the same as my issue. Now for example when I hover over the node that has the name `Son of A` I want this node with this name to be highlighted in the second and third tree as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your fiddle to show how to render the trees with a single function, and implemented the highlighting: https://jsfiddle.net/j2mhokbz/1/

With regards to creating a single function, you have identified what is changing... the data object from the array. So simply add that as a parameter of the draw function and pass in the slice of the data that you want. Note the new `data` parameter, and the fact that this is passed to the update function.

```
draw('#svg1', treeData[0]);
draw('#svg2', treeData[1]);
draw('#svg3', treeData[2]);

function draw(selector, data) {
  ...
  update(data);

  function update(dataForUpdate) {
    ...
    var nodes = tree.nodes(dataForUpdate).reverse(),
    ...
  }
}
```

For the highlighting, the basic principle is to add a `highlighted` class to the circle and a new css rule that defines how the circle should look when it has a `highlighted` class.

On mouseover, you select the sibling text element of a circle by first selecting the circle's parent node (a `g` element) and then selecting that node's child `text` element.

Then extract the text from the `text` element and use the `filter` method to only return elements that are bound to data with the same name. Then add the `highlighted` class.

On mouseout, the same procedure is used except that an empty string set as the class, which removes the highlighting.

As it is basically the same procedure, you can create a single function to set or unset the highlighted class for nodes with the same name. See the code below:

```
d3.selectAll('circle')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    setHighlightedForSimilarNodes(this, true);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    setHighlightedForSimilarNodes(this, false);
  });

function setHighlightedForSimilarNodes(node, isHighlighted) {
  const text = d3.select(node.parentNode).select('text').text();
  d3.selectAll('circle').filter((d, i) => {
    return d.name === text;
  })
  .attr('class', isHighlighted ? 'highlighted' : '');
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @lemming .
p.s. I really find it beautiful how you did the function setHighlightedForSimilarNodes. Thank you, I appreciate it!